# Enable dataZoom with mouse without using toolbox

Tags: javascript, echarts

I would like to enable this type of zoom [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-tooltip-touch), the one you can enable by clicking on the toolbox icon "zoom" which lets you zoom by selecting an area of the chart with the mouse. I want to enable it without the use of the toolbox, I want it by default and not displaying the toolbox either.

This is how my chart looks:

[image]

I want it to keep looking like this, no slider on the bottom and no toolbox, but being able to zoom on the X axis by selecting an area. I would zoom out by double clicking.

Is there a way to enable that type of datazoom without using toolbox?